# I want to use internet on my android device while connected to my laptop's hotspot

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, internet, android

I am building an app that will send data to a Python server hosted on my laptop. However, it will also need an internet connection to send some stuff to Google Cloud. When my android device connects to the hotspot on my laptop, it no longer has access to the internet. I was able to deal with this by using wired internet with my laptop. That way, my android device has internet while it is connected to the laptop's hotspot.

However, this won't be possible in open areas where an ethernet cable (or wired internet in general) won't be available. In such a case, how do I connect to the hotspot on my laptop while also using mobile data on my android device to connect to Google cloud. **I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and my android device is a Oneplus 5.**

Answer (score 0):

Let the mobile device be the hotspot.  You should be able to access the laptop that way.  It would likely require changing the configuration of you app though.
It would also give the laptop access to your mobile network.